# Carousel using Sencha Touch on a panel above a panel

Tags: html, sencha-touch, carousel

[image]

I have create a floating panel above a panel and have added carousel to the floating panel.
Now the problem is that while carousing i can see all the items that were added. I want only one item to get displayed on the floating panel while others to be hidden and not be displayed outside the floating panel. How can i achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Code:

```
var App = new Ext.Application({
name: 'CarouselDemo',
useLoadMask: true,

launch: function () {    
    overlayView.show();
}
});

var overlayView = new Ext.Panel({
floating: true,    
centered: true,    
styleHtmlContent: true,
width:600,    
height:600,
items: [
{
xtype    : 'carousel',
ui       : 'light',
direction: 'horizontal',
items: [
    {   html: '<p>Carousels can be vertical and given a ui of "light" or "dark".</p>' 
    },
    {   html: 'Card #2'   
    },
    {   html: 'Card #3'  
    }
    ]
}]            
});
```

Comment: Can you show us the code?

Comment: i have added the code..check above..

Comment: hey i dont know whether the way i have done is right or wrong. new to this. if you can help with correct way than most thankful.